# Newby trying to link database single value to onclick button with some conditions

Tags: database, image, button, radio-button, coding-style

I'm trying to make a deck builder for a game (cardsandcastle), I will show every card (each one will be a button) that will change a value of how many cards (database) of that one will be on the deck when clicked (if/switch condition with radio button options).

What I'm asking is how or what code needs to put on the click event to set that value on my database (have searched for something similar, but only found big codes that cand identify which code belongs to database interaction)

Comment: What programming language are you using? We're going to need to see the code which makes up the form as well, in order to be able to assist you.

Comment: This is all the auto-code generated by wix:
// For full API documentation, including code examples

$w.onReady(function () {
 //TODO: write your page related code here.

});

export function yennarit(event) {
 //Add your code for this event here: 
}

I dont know what $w.onready activates or generate. But yennarith event its generated by tool on the picture properties (on click), so i asume if i put some code there it will run. If thats the case i want to change a value on my database, so if anyone can share a code recipe or something like "databasename.changevalue (column.row)"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. That code is simple javascript, so it might be worth asking your question with a `javascript` tag.

I was unaware of this, but apparently Wix provides a [development platform](https://support.wix.com/en/article/about-corvid-by-wix) called [Corvid](https://www.wix.com/corvid/). Neither Wix nor Corvid are tags that can be used on Stack Overflow, but the platform makes use of [features](https://www.wix.com/corvid/features) like `node.js`, which is [well represented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) here.

Probably the best place for you to start is in the Tutorials and Examples provided by Wix. Check out:

- [Creating a to-do list](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/corvid-tips-and-updates/example-todomvc)
- [Creating a Form for Editing Data in a Database Collection](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-tutorial-creating-a-form-for-editing-data-in-a-database-collection)
- [Displaying Database Content on a Regular Page](https://support.wix.com/en/article/displaying-database-content-on-a-regular-page)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I finally can change the values i wanted (but i know im wasting some code or are pointless, but it works). 

I dont know why does it need 2 arrays (take the first and substitute the second??)

If there is any extra coded that can be deleted, i will make the change. And the next thing to do is make and if-case to pick the value on my radio buttons (1-3 value)

Comment: export function yennaroth(event) {
  let toSave1 = {
  "_id":        "46f9e52a-58ca-4324-a39d-dcad6d79e1d6",
  "cardamount":   3,
  };

let toSave2 = {
  "_id":        "46f9e52a-58ca-4324-a39d-dcad6d79e1d6",
  "cardamount":   3,
};
wixData.bulkSave("Data", [toSave1, toSave2])
  .then( (results) => {
    let inserted = results.inserted; // 2
    let insertedIds = results.insertedItemIds; // see below
    let updated = results.updated; // 0
    let skipped = results.skipped; // 0
    let errors = results.errors; // []
  } )
  .catch( (err) => {
    let errorMsg = err;
  } );